# Is there a place to pull satellite imagery based on latitude and longitude?

Tags: geospatial, api

Is there a freely available service to call, via API, and pull satellite imagery using latitude and longitude coordinates?  Something akin to Google Maps. It doesn't have to the latest image, just a general image in the last few years?

Comment: A great source of satellite data is [Earth Explorer](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) run by USGS.

Comment: Thank you @Hornbydd. Does that tool allow API and I'm not seeing it?  I have a list of tens of thousands of lat/lon coordinates that I'd like to run through.

Comment: I've used their bulk data downloader in the past not sure if it exposes anything via an API, see [help](https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/EEHelp/ee_help).

Comment: Yes I read the docs and watched the video on the bulk  downloader.  What I didn't see was instructions on uploading bulk coordinates to make up the order.  It seems like I would have to manually input each one.

Comment: I assume when you say you have tens of thousands of coordinates that actually lots of them would fall within a single satellite scene and you don't actually want tens of thousands of satellite images which if you did and they were multispectral like sentinel then you are are probably looking at downloading and storing 100's of terrabytes and at that point good luck! :)

Comment: Ha!  Yes I do mean tens of thousands of coordinates.  These photos are actually quite useful in deep neural nets.  Not being a GIS specialist, I'm not sure what sentinel is, but what I'm looking for is each coordinate centered in the photo, downloaded as a .jpg or .png as if I were pulling from google maps...only free.

Comment: check [this](http://geologyandpython.com/get-landsat-8.html) out

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you for sticking with me and providing help.

Comment: @Hornbydd, you should consider expanding your final helpful comment into an answer, since it did seem to answer the poster's question.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting option is "Sentinelsat", an open source Python based tool which makes searching, downloading and retrieving the metadata of Sentinel satellite images from the Copernicus Open Access Hub easy. The Sentinel data are global open data (Radar, optical and thermal data are available).

Software and instructions at https://sentinelsat.readthedocs.io/

For a global, ready-to-use coverage, see "Sentinel-2 cloudless" at https://s2maps.eu/ - they offer also OGC Web services to access the dataset.